# Visual Studio Code - Debug With Chrome - Breakpoints Run At Start, Not When Met

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code

***EDIT: I have found the solution. Since others may make the same mistake, I will put the answer at the bottom.***

I am using Visual Studio Code. I am new to it.

I have Debugger For Chrome and Debugger For Edge installed.

I have Live Server installed.

I have launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch Chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "pwa-chrome",
            "url": "http://127.0.0.1:5500/a.html",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have my basic html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="myfunc()">Click</button>
</body>
<script>
    function myfunc(){
        alert("clicked");
    }
</script>
</html>
```

I have my breakpoint on the line `alert("clicked");`.

I click the Debugging icon on the left with the spider, and then click the green button to launch.

Now the weird bit:

The program launches and breaks immediately on the `alert` line, even though the button has not been pressed.

I continue.

But then when I click the button and expect the break point to be met. It is not. The alert occurs without breaking at all.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

***Solution:***

It does not like the `<script>` outside the body. If you change the html file to have the `<script>` inside the body, then it works fine.

Like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="myfunc()">Click</button>

    <script>
        function myfunc(){
            alert("clicked");
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was going wrong.

It does not like the  outside the body. If you change the html file to have the  inside the body, then it works fine.

Like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="myfunc()">Click</button>

    <script>
        function myfunc(){
            alert("clicked");
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```